# Java delegation model to support many Event Types

Tags: java, design-patterns, delegation

I have a class which needs to add additional properties based on Event Name. There can be many event names. How to better design this class so that it supports easy enhancement and maintenance in future.

```
public class MessageDecoratorServiceImpl implements MessageaDecorator {

        @Override
        public BaseMessage addMessageProperties(BaseMessage inputMessage ){

            return decorateMessage(inputMessage);
        }
        BaseMessage decorateMessage(BaseMessage inputMessage) {
            if(inputMessage.getEventName().equals("NewSubscription")) {
                decorateSubscription(inputMessage);
            }else if( inputMessage.getEventName().equals("NewContact") ) {
                decorateNewContact(inputMessage);
            }

        }
        BaseMessage decorateSubscription(BaseMessage inputMessage) {
            inputMessage.getProperties().put("customFiled", "customValue");
            return inputMessage;
        }
        BaseMessage decorateNewContact(BaseMessage inputMessage) {
            inputMessage.getProperties().put("contactCustomFiled", "value");
            return inputMessage;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a distinct decorator implementation by event type.
It reduces the coupling between them.

```
public class MessageDecoratorSubscription implements MessageDecorator {    
        @Override
        public BaseMessage addMessageProperties(BaseMessage inputMessage ){
            inputMessage.getProperties().put("customFiled", "customValue");
            return inputMessage;
        }    
}


public class MessageDecoratorNewContact implements MessageDecorator {    
        @Override
        public BaseMessage addMessageProperties(BaseMessage inputMessage ){
            inputMessage.getProperties().put("contactCustomFiled", "value");
            return inputMessage;
        }    
}
```

And invoke them as :

```
new MessageDecoratorSubscription(myBaseMessage);
```

or

```
new MessageDecoratorNewContact(myBaseMessage);
```

Now adding/removing/changing a event processing doesn't affect others.

About these conditional statements :

```
if(inputMessage.getEventName().equals("NewSubscription")) {
    decorateSubscription(inputMessage);
}else if( inputMessage.getEventName().equals("NewContact") ) {
    decorateNewContact(inputMessage);
}
```

It should so be avoided. It is error prone.
You could replace them by a `Map<String, MessageDecorator>` field with event types as keys and decorator implementations as values.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What if i want to add some event method at run time?